# Intel Graphics 515 issue 16.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

Good day to everyone !

I own a Dell Latitude 7370 notebook which comes with an Core m7-6y75 and a Intel 515 integrated GPU. The screen is 13,3" with a resolution of 3200x1800 pixels.

The desktop runs very smoothly, but I have some issues while booting. First, the purple Ubuntu-boot screen builds up very slowly from the bottom of my screen to the top. It takes about 5 seconds before it is filled. When the desktop apears, there are a few graphic glitches like the top menu bar appearing in the middle of the screen. It takes 5 - 10 seconds before it corrects itself and loads the left menu bar.

I've set the desktop resolution to 1920x1080 because any higher resolution will make everything so small that it is practically unreadable.

Hopefully there will be a fix.

Sincerely,
Ruud Bos

Comment: You should always use the native resolution and adjust the scaling of elements and fonts when using higher resolutions. The issue you're reporting has to do that: It starts with the native resolution and then your settings kick in, the result being a few temporary glitches due to down scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your graphic drivers to recent stable release. Intel provides beautiful GUI based **graphics update tool for linux** which updates the graphic drives to latest release. You can download it from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/blogs/vega/2016/released-intelr-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it doesn't work. First. the tool says that I have a i915 GPU (I have a Intel 515) and then it says that my distribution (Yakkety Yak - 16.10) is not supported.

Comment: I believe the tool  is supported only on 16.04LTS.